# "No such slot" when trying to use QTimer

Tags: c++, qt

I have a graphics view wrapper defined as `MyQGraphicsView::MyQGraphicsView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)`

Within this, I am trying to set a timed GUI update event with QTimers.

```
public slots:
    void colourGUI(std::vector<Item *> &items);
```

However,  when I try to call it, I get an error.  Here is how I'm calling it...

```
// timer...
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(colourGUI(items)));
timer->start(2000);
```

I get the following error:

```
Object::connect: No such slot MyQGraphicsView::colourGUI(items)
```

What gives?  Have I set this up wrong?

Comment: What do you except the the value of the `items` argument when the slot is invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code. First, you are trying to connect a signal and slot with different signatures.

You would need<sup>(1)</sup>

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout(std::vector<Item*>)), this, SLOT(colourGUI(std::vector<Item*>)));
```

instead of:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(colourGUI(items)));
```

However this will only work if the Qt metaobject system knows how to marshal this type, but it doesn't. You either need to register it or use one of the Qt collections, for example `QList`. And timer doesn't have such signal anyway.

<sup>(1) the SLOT "description" must not contain argument names and must contain the types of the arguments in order to be able to marshal them correctly.</sup>

Comment: So in that case, how would I use the QTimer object to run a method that takes an arbitrary parameter after some amount of time?

Comment: You can't do that. What you can is store that arbitrary parameter as state somewhere (for example, a member in the class which has the slot colorGUI).

Comment: The marshal sentence isn't correct, marshaling is only needed if you use a QueuedConnection. DirectConnection (the default when both objects live in the same thread) works with any type.

Comment: I have this problem as well. I did `connect(_frameTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(fetchNextFrame()));` but I get a `Object::connect: No such signal VideoPlayerWidget::timeout()` warning. `_frameTimer` is a QTimer. How can this happen?

Comment: according to your error message, _frameTimer is a VideoPlayerWidget (which may or may not be a descendant of QTimer). Make sure that you use public inheritance and that your class contains the Q_OBJECT macro. If that was the problem, rebuild everything after the change (you might need to manually remove the generated Makefiles). If that doesn't help, post a question with code.